# How to make a tbody vertically scrollable and the whole table horizontally scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to scroll the table vertically with headers "sticked" into top of the table and scroll the table horizontally with headers on top of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get away fairly easily using the `overflow` CSS property (see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp). More specifically, you can use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to constraint the scrolling behaviour in a specific axis